# Confirmation on href link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a href and confirmation on the click of that href.

```html
<a href="stackoverflow.com" onclick="return confirm('Sure?')">Go to SO</a>
```

But I want confirmation from the user if they hit the href link directly by typing the URL.

If it is not possible, is there any other way to achieve this? My href page is php page.

Comment: What action would happen if they type in the URL and click `cancel`?

Comment: @EvanKennedy If I copy the href link and hit it via browser, it is not asking for confirmation

Comment: You mean if the user types the url on browser's address bar, right?

Comment: @Sougata Yes Exactly

Comment: Are you the owner of the page or can put your own script on it? If so, my answer should help. If not, you'll have to use Sakuto's answer. EDIT: I mean the page you want the confirmation on. In your example it would be on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'll want to do is put the confirmation on the actual page (if you are the owner). Make sure to put this in the `<head>` section so that it won't show anything on the page before it asks the user.

Like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(!confirm('Are you sure?')) {
    location.href = 'some page to redirect to on cancel';
}
</script>
```

Comment: You mean put this snippet on my php page at the top? My PHP page is the target

Comment: I'm assuming you have some sort of `<head>` section. If not, go ahead and put it before the first bit of actual content that the user would see. Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/evankennedy/o39cmrxa/

Comment: Yes At the top of my php page I added your script inside head section of html element.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `onbeforeunload` to prevent user leaving the page without confirmation:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  return 'Sure?';
};
```

Comment: Wait wait wait..... Ok. So It will be executed for all of my pages. Right? I want confirmation to load a particular page.

Comment: So check the introduced url!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a page dedicated to redirect the user, you could, for example, store link on your database with an id and the link, and just link the user to `yourlink?id=<yourid>`, then display the warning on this page :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="tip deleteuser" data-original-title="Delete" href="<?php echo $site_path['admin_url']; ?>user/delete/<?php echo $allUSers[$i]['id'];?>"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-1x"></i></a>&nbsp;


$('.deleteuser').click(function () {

        var confirmation = confirm("Are you sure that you want to delete this user ?");

        if (confirmation) {

            return true;

        } else {

            return false;

        }

    });
```